# joomla 3.5 creates multiple duplicates of articles

Tags: joomla

I have a joomla 3.5 website that at some point started to show strange behaviors. In the back-panel, all the articles have been duplicated around 20 times and each set of suplicated articles share the same ID (I checked the DB and it correctly contains only one entry for each article). This problem happens also when I create a new article, since the system creates also a lot of copy of it. I am also not able to delete the duplicated copies, because any action (publishing, unpublishing, trashing, ...) that I apply to one of the copy, affects also all the other ones (which makes sense since they share the same ID).
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have touched the query that presents the list, namely the join because if this is not set correctly it has several occurring repeated times, so with the same id.
Activate joomla debugging and so see the query that generates the list so try it out to find the error.